# Search by location in ElasticSearch using Nest c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have store that each store have a location that type is Coordinates2D
I want to search by location in 10km distance
I write this query but not return any store

```
 await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Store>(s => s.Index("store").From(from).Size(size)
        .Query(query => query.Bool(b => b.Filter(filter => filter
        .GeoDistance(geo => geo
        .Field(f => f.Location)
        .Distance(10, DistanceUnit.Kilometers).Location(lat, lon)
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the `"location"` field. It needs to be mapped as a `geo_point` data type to be able to perform a geo distance query on it

Comment: How can do this @RussCam

Comment: Easiest way is to call the mapping API endpoint: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

Comment: Tnx for your guide @RussCam